# How to view your website changes before deploying them live from Forge?

Tags: laravel, web, github, forge

I have set up a linode server and I am using laravel forge to handle the PHP etc. I am also using Github with laravel and set up the continuous integration. Albeit, I'm not super clear about most of the set up and neither do I understand how they work entirely, I have this entire thing set up to get my site live.

What I want to know is,

How do I see a development site which I am making changes to constantly and a live site which is what everyone else who visits the URL sees.

Is there a way I can push changes to a development branch and I can see only the changes I am making but in the master branch is where the live site lives that the world is able to see as finished.

Comment: The most basic answer is that you should have a copy running on your development machine (possibly via Vagrant / Homestead). Do you have one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup your site locally with

- Valet: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/valet
- or Homestead: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead

Both very well documented.

If you are simply trying to setup a staging environment. Setup two forge sites one which pulls from a development-branch and one which pulls from the master branch, that way you can test your changes on a live-server first without actually exposing it to your end users.

Comment: This helps! Thank you so much.